# Get Gulp Task Output sequentially in Vscode

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I was already successful to automate my build commands inside the "tasks.json" file. But sadly "tasks.json" or vscode does not offer an option to set custom environment variables (which would be a really really really nice and needed feature).
I don't want to change a couple of lines just to specify the program which I want to build (there are a couple in this project). I was able to do a workaround and set an windows environment variable, but for this workaround I need to restart vscode if I change the environment variable.

Therefore I tried to use GULP-Task to start my build process, because with gulp task I set file global variables. I was already able to get my tasks running in gulp, but with gulp tasks I don't see the progress of my building task in the output sequentially, I just get the output when he is finished in a big "blop".

I tried a couple of things, like piping, writing to file (this worked sequentially), but the output on the output-window is still displayed as a "blop". Therefore I want to ask if it is possible to get an sequential output of my running task with gulp?

This is how I start my build task:

```
gulp.task('BuildDebug', function (cb) {
    exec(buildCommand + debugCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? :D

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my solution was to use the extension "vscode-commandbar" and don't use gulp tasks anymore.